# OpenSSL building errors in CentOS 6.02 64 bit OS

Tags: c++, linux, openssl, centos

I am facing some problems in building openssl in CentOS 6.02 64 bit OS. Whenever I try to build it I face the errors followings:-

```
md5-x86_64.s:41: Error: 0xd76aa478 out range of signed 32bit displacement
md5-x86_64.s:50: Error: 0xe8c7b756 out range of signed 32bit displacement
md5-x86_64.s:68: Error: 0xc1bdceee out range of signed 32bit displacement
md5-x86_64.s:77: Error: 0xf57c0faf out range of signed 32bit displacement
md5-x86_64.s:95: Error: 0xa8304613 out range of signed 32bit displacement
Many more errors like this.
```

Comment: What version of OpenSSL? What version of bintuils?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

It's a problem with the addressing in the assembly code. (32 bit vs 64 bit addressing.) There was a [bug](http://rt.openssl.org/Ticket/Display.html?id=2094&user=guest&pass=guest) filed for this.

For a quick fix try recompiling with the `no-asm` option.

```
cd <openssl-source-directory>
./config no-asm
make && make install
```

EDIT: To resolve the errors caused by not having the -fPIC flag: do a `make clean`, change the line for `./config no-asm` to `./config no-asm -fPIC`, and run `make && make install`.

Comment: how can I compile with no-asm option? please write the whole command.

Comment: @NaseefUrRahman You might need to do a `make clean` before you perform the `./config no-asm` command. That will clean out the objects you compiled before when you were not using the `no-asm` option.

Answer (score 4):

Open the file 'openssl-x/crypto/md5/asm/md5-x86_64.pl'

Then make the following changes:

After:

> sub round1_step
>
> {
>        my ($pos, $dst, $x, $y, $z, $k_next, $T_i, $s) = @_;

Add the following line:

```
+ $T_i = unpack("l",pack("l", hex($T_i))); # convert to 32-bit signed decimal
```

Similarly, add the same line for sub round2_step, sub round3_step & sub round4_step